# can we enable and disable notification in app using API level permission in Android?

Tags: android

I have a notification feature in my application which shows timely notification in notification bar, when user don't want notification they can always go back to settings and disable it. Is there any API level notification prompt which lets user to "enable" and "disable" notification from application itself.

I know this can be done explicitly too by disabling and enabling flag in application, but I was wanted to check if through API it is possible

Regards

Answer (score 0):

No there is no api that is exposed to the SDK. But native Settings application uses following method from notification manager internally.

```
setNotificationsEnabledForPackage(packageName, mAppEntry.info.uid, enabled);
```